# Numpy/Scipy - printing matrix class as floating point

Tags: python, matrix, floating-point, numpy, scipy

I have an 8x8 matrix in numpy (matrix class) and it keeps printing it out in scientific notation.  Is there a way I can force it to print everything in floating point.

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [`set_printoptions`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html):

```
>>> a = numpy.arange(10, dtype='f8')
>>> a /= 100000
>>> a
array([  0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e-05,   2.00000000e-05,
         3.00000000e-05,   4.00000000e-05,   5.00000000e-05,
         6.00000000e-05,   7.00000000e-05,   8.00000000e-05,
         9.00000000e-05])
>>> numpy.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
>>> a
array([ 0.     ,  0.00001,  0.00002,  0.00003,  0.00004,  0.00005,
        0.00006,  0.00007,  0.00008,  0.00009])
```